# ffmpeg "d" key pressing during convert

Tags: debugging, ffmpeg

I press the key "d" during ffmpeg convert process.
The conversion stopped. Than I press ENTER, I get a debug message and the conversion continues.

This is not problem? The conversion will be good?

Comment: Please describe your action and problem in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the conversion will be fine. Pressing `d` will cause ffmpeg to wait for further user input. Now enter an integer. This will cause all decoders and encoders used in the command to print debug data corresponding to the level entered. Not all de/encoders have something to say for any given level. Press `-` to exit back to normal verbosity.

Note that conversion hasn't exactly stopped. If you let the prompt sit, encoders and decoders will fill their buffers in multi-threaded mode. Verify this by seeing the `frame=` count jump when you revert the verbosity.